# Is ASP.NET MVC a Good Fit for an Event Ticketing Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Good Afternoon,

I'm rebuilding an event ticketing site originally developed using ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms and am considering using ASP.NET MVC2 for the rebuilt solution.  I like the idea of friendly URLs as the current site has very long query string URLs for each specified event.  MVC2 also appeals from a separation of concerns point of view as well.  The biggest unknown for me is will MVC2 handle calls to 3 separate web services (SOAP and REST) to get ticket availability?  That is, does the controller functionality permit use of such web services?  Finally, MVC3 is due to RTM in January.  Am I better off waiting for MVC3, or can I start the project in MVC2 and port it later?

Thanks for all your advice and insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC can handle any HTTP request as ASP.NET forms does. Indeed you should [consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715914/how-to-use-soap-in-asp-net-mvc) to use WCF for handling SOAP queries. And yes, sure you can easely create REST API with MVC.

It is better to start now, with ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2. It is very stable and nice. This will minimize migration work. Welcome to MVC happy world!

Answer (score 1):

The controller will let you run pretty much any code you want.

I just started using MVC in a big project and it's turning out well. We went with MVC 3 and it's been a little tricky living on the edge, but it seems to have a lot of nice improvements. I'm extremely happy to be using MVC instead of Web Forms. To me, it seems to flow smoothly instead of fighting with the way the web works.