# Check if a URL is a valid Feed

Tags: c#, feed, argotic

I'm using Argotic Syndication Framework for processing feeds.

But the problem is, if I pass a URL to Argotic, which is not a valid feed (for example, `http://stackoverflow.com` which is a html page, not feed), the program hangs (I mean, Argotic stays in an infinity loop)

So, How to check if a URL is pointing to a valid feed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From .NET 3.5 you can do this below. It will throw an exception if it's not a valid feed.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Xml;

public bool TryParseFeed(string url)
{
    try
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(url));

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            Debug.Print(item.Title.Text);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you can try parsing the document by your own:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n<event>This is a Test</event>";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Then try checking the root element. It should be the feed element and have "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" namespace:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
```

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/systemservicemodelsyndication

Comment: Since my project in a web application, So I can't trust the header. Someone may give an invalid feed, but valid XML and valid root element, Then my app hang... :(

Comment: Thanks for the update. But a question: `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` supports what feed formats?

Comment: <feed> in Atom 1.0 and <rss> in RSS 2.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Comment: The advantage of your method is it does not need any web requests to determinate if it is valid or not. But the disadvantage is, Argotic supports much more feed types, but `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` doesn't.

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto A problem with using SyndicationFeed.Load() is that it will often run into dtd errors on "valid" rss and atom feeds.  The issue is that the feed might be "invalid" according to the spec, but valid according to the apps that use them, hence SyndicationFeed.Load() eliminates a bunch of good feeds.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/feed/). It has [SOAP API](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/soap.html).

Comment: Thank you. seems that your answer is the best. But can you explain some more about SOAP API? How to contact that API? Is it possible to call that api with GET requests?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi check this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512390.aspx if it's not clear I'll create an example later.

Comment: It would be nice if you create an example :)  Thanks

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi ok. in 9-10 hours I'll be free for this.

Comment: There is a limitation in this service: 1 request per second. So I can't make requests to this service from server side. And about client-side, also it is not allowing ajax requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997256/call-a-external-web-page-cross-domain-with-javascript , Isn't there any way to use this service from client-side?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the content type. It has to be `text/xml`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945201/how-to-get-content-type-of-a-web-address) to find the content type.

you can use this code:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
if (request != null)
{
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    string contentType = "";

    if (response != null)
        contentType = response.ContentType;
}
```

*thanks to the answer of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945201/how-to-get-content-type-of-a-web-address)*

**Update**

To check if it is a feed address you can use [W3C Feed Validation](http://validator.w3.org/appc/) service.

**Update2**

as BurundukXP said it has a SOAP API. to work with it you can read the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715914/how-to-use-soap-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Every XML is not a Feed. Also please read my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee - Your core statement: "It has to be text/xml" is incorrect.  First, any response can indicate any content type, so that result alone is not authoritative.  Additionally, text/rss+xml is a valid content type for RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just have it transformed into valid RSS/ATOM, you can use http://feedcleaner.nick.pro/ to have it sanitized. Alternatively, you can [fork the project](https://github.com/nickmoline/feedsanitizer).